# Why aren't values in initializer_list type-checked?

Tags: c++, g++, std, initializer-list, list-initialization

How does this compile and run without any warnings or errors? I don't understand how the dereferenced value of `current`, which is an int, can be assigned to the string `a` without any problem.

```
class Test {
public:
  string a;

  Test(initializer_list<int> t) {
    auto current = t.begin();

    // I am assigning an int to a string!
    a = *current;
  }
};

int main() {
  Test test{65};
  printf("%s\n", test.a.c_str());
}
```

The printed string is

```
A
```

In contrast, this very similar code produces a compile-time error:

```
int main() {
  initializer_list<int> test1{65};
  auto current = test1.begin();
  string b = *current;

  return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```
error: no viable conversion from 'const int' to 'std::__1::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >')
  string b = *current;
```

Comment: Note that `string b = *current;` is not an assignment, it is a constructor invocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `a = *current;` and `string b = *current;` perform different things.

`a = *current;` is an assignment, which leads to the invocation of `operator=`, and [`std::string::operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) has an overloading taking `char`, which makes `a = *current;` work (after the [implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_conversions) from `int` to `char`).

> 4) Replaces the contents with character ch as if by `assign(std::addressof(ch), 1)`

`string b = *current;` is an initialization, which tries to call the [constructor of `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) to initialize `b`. But these constructors don't have such overloading taking `int` (or `char`), then `string b = *current;` won't work.